# Accessing global variable from TypeScript module

Tags: typescript

The compiler compiles fine but I get the following error at runtime: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: bar is not defined`.

### index.ts

```js
import Foo from "./modules/foo";

const bar: string[] = [];

const foo = new Foo();
```

### foo.ts

```js
declare let bar: string[];

export default class Foo {
    constructor() {
        console.log(bar);
    }
}
```

How should I proceed if I want to access the bar variable within the foo module?

Answer (score 0):

So I can now easily answer my previous question:

**interfaces.ts**

```js
export default interface InterfaceWindow extends Window {
  bar: string[];
}
```

**index.ts**

```js
import Foo from "./modules/foo";
import InterfaceWindow from "./interfaces.ts"

declare var window: InterfaceWindow;

window.bar = [];

const foo = new Foo();
```

**foo.ts**

```js
import InterfaceWindow from "./interfaces";

declare var window: InterfaceWindow;

export default class Foo {
    constructor() {
        console.log(window.bar); // []
    }
}
```